# tensorflow dynamically create placeholders

Tags: tensorflow

At each iteration I want to dynamically provide how many placeholders I want and then will feed data to them. Is that possible and how ? I tried to create the whole model (placeholders, loss, optimizer) inside epoch loop but that gave uninitialised variables error.

At present I have n=5 placeholders each of shape=(1, k) in a list and I feed data to them. But n needs to dynamically defined during data feeding inside epoch loop.

Comment: Can't you have 1 placeholder of shape [None, k], where you can adapt the first dimension at will?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot are these two same thing ? Consider the use case: those 5 placeholders are word vectors with dim=k and 5 time steps and I am training a RNN. Will the BPTT work if I consider yours?

Comment: If your input is a sequence of word vectors (size `k`) of unknown length (call it `N`), you placeholder should be of shape `[None, k]`. Your model should then be able to handle variable sizes of input, if it is a RNN.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot yes I know. But will BPTT  work in that case?. And how will I be able to iterate over the N vectors inside the placeholder?

Comment: I am not familiar with the tensorflow models, but maybe [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) or [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3sok8k/tensorflow_basic_rnn_example_with_variable_length/) might be helpful !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you misunderstood what a tensor is.

If you think of a tensor like a multi-dimensional list, you can understand that having a dynamically number of placeholder with a shape `[1, k]` is no sense.

Instead, you have to use a single tensor.

Thus, define your input placeholder as a tensor with shape `[None, 1, k]`.

```
placeholder_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, k])
```

With this statement you define a placeholder with `tf.float32` type and an undefined number of elements (the `None` part) with shape `[1,k]`.

In every iteration, you have to feed the placeholder with the right values. Eg running

```
result = sess.run(defined_op, feed_dict={
    placeholder_: numpy_ndarray_with_N_elements_with_shape_1_k
})
```

In that way you don't need to define new variables into the computational graph (that simply doesn't work) but feed it with the desired values.

Comment: when I had n [1,k] placeholders, I could iterate over them in the graph. Now what can I do with the single [None, 1, k] placeholder ?

Comment: Everything? You can iterate inside the graph, extracting slices of the placeholder. Each slice extracted is logically the same as a single placeholder without the first dimension.

Comment: cool. but when extracting slides how will I know how many slide to extract because the 1st dimension is given as None.

Comment: You feed the placeholder with a defined amount of elements with shape [1,k]. Thus you know how many elements are in that placeholder.
In addiction, you can extract the real shape of the tensor and thus know how many elements are present dinamycally. Just call `_placeholder.get_shape()[0].value` to get the placeholder first dimension value (when the placeholder has been fed)

Comment: then I need the shape at the time of graph creation because at first I am creating a placeholder of shape [None,1, k] and then will slice all rows from it each of shape [1,k]. Possible?

Comment: Yes it's possibile. But I still do not understand why you need to load the whole set of elements with shape [1,k] and do not feed the placeholder with new values on every iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113806/discussion-between-nessuno-and-rajarshee-mitra).