# Create placeholders for tensors of dynamic size at every iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating the placeholder for a tensor in the following way:

```
self.sample_set = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,None,self.max_input_right]) --- (1)
```

Now I want to slice this tensor of shape [None,self.max_input_right]. Basically the above tensor consist of list of values and now I want to extract those values from the list. But with every iteration of feed_dict, the size of this list changes.
So after step (1), I was looking if I can perform something like this:

```
for i in range(self.k):
        self.ans_set = tf.slice(self.sample_set, [0,i])
        self.ans_sets.append(self.ans_set)
```

where the value of k would change with every feed_dict. But I am unable to understand how should I pass the changing value of k while building the graph.

This question might look similar to previously posted question:
[tensorflow dynamically create placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621841/tensorflow-dynamically-create-placeholders)

But this answer didn't help me to find the answer.

Comment: What about having a fixed size placeholder and fill it with NaN or zeros in case of shorter input? Changing the shape of the input vector is in general not a good idea, how is your network going to adapt to it?

Comment: @alec_djinn Basically, I am getting a list of values from a cluster which is then fed to the network. The size of the cluster would vary in every iteration.

Comment: I assume your network has a defined number of input nodes, or not?

Comment: @alec_djinn I have input nodes for other attributes being fed but I am unable to create variable placeholders for the varying list of values fed to the network.

Comment: I see... can't you set a max_len for that particular input? if you know that the max_len is 100 (for example), then you can set a placeholder that long, and for any shorter input you just need to fill in NaN until max_len is reached.

Comment: @alec_djinn Yes, that's a kind of way I was thinking to create a large tensor and fill the empty ones maybe with zeroes.

Comment: It sounds the easiest way to go for me

Answer (score 0):

For the use case in your example, you can simply use [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack):

```
self.sample_set = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,None,self.max_input_right])
self.ans_sets = tf.unstack(self.sample_set)
```

This will give you the list of 3D tensors. By default `unstack` works on axis 0 but you can also change this.

Comment: This raises the following error: 
    self.ans_sets = tf.unstack(self.sample_set)
  File "/nfs/stak/users/chattepu/tensorflow_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 974, in unstack
    raise ValueError("Cannot infer num from shape %s" % value_shape)
ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?, 160)

Comment: Oh damn. Maybe I should have properly read the docs I linked before writing this answer... I'll delete it soon. Or maybe we let it stay up so that people see what _doesn't_ work.